# click_link image in cucumber

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cucumber

```
<a href="/videos/21-running">
  <img height="120" src="/images/sample-image.jpg" alt="Running">
</a>
```

Please support me a way click link in cucumber by alt or src. Thanks.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Assuming you are using `capybara` to back your cucumber specs something like the following step should do the trick.

```
When /^I follow image link "([^"]*)"$/ do |img_alt|
    find(:xpath, "//img[@alt = '#{img_alt}']/parent::a").click()
end
```

In the spec you can now just say

```
When I follow image link "Running"
```

The general idea is that you need some kind of custom step to handle this.